# UIDocumentInteractionController stopped working for Tumblr

Tags: ios, tumblr, sharing, uidocumentinteraction

I have this UIDocumentInteractionController to share a photo on Instagram and Tumblr. Instagram works great, but the one for Tumblr stopped working.

I use @"com.tumblr.photo" for UTI, @".tumblrphoto" for file extension. Does anyone know if there were any recent changes to Tumblr? Is this an ios 8 issue?

Comment: I'd say it has something to do with Tumblr Share extensions. They've stated here: https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK that they "maintain the support as of 9/29/2015" (which looks like a typo), and that it may not be maintained in the future due to said Share extensions. Just a guess though, didn't find any proof of this.

Comment: guess #2: maybe you accidentally deleted Tumblr app?